# Can anybody identify this SiTel IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, components

I am trying to identify an IC in order to repair a circuit board. Here is a photo of the IC in question:

[image: Photo of the IC]

For reference, the markings on it are:

```
UU0715
SC14470
BNF128VV
GP9746.1
```

And here are the clues I have found so far:

- This circuit board is on the main board inside a [RedOctane X-Plorer Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RedOctane_X-Plorer_Controller) (model 95065).

  - Two important things to note about this controller are that it is a wired controller, and I believe that it supports connecting to [Xbox 360 accessories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_360_accessories), including headsets with analog audio, so I believe that the controller must have DACs somewhere for the audio in & out. This might be the purpose of the Xbox chip (see below).
  - Judging from its size, and the fact that the only other ICs in the entire controller are a flash chip, accelerometer, and some tiny Xbox chip, my theory is that this SiTel chip functions as the main processor for the board. This is strange considering that SiTel seems to be a company focused mostly on phones/communication, and this is a wired controller.
- The manufacturer logo is from a company called SiTel. Here is another SiTel chip (a DECT baseband processor) with the same logo and similar markings.

  - I believe that it is a different company from the former US-based ["Sitel"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitel).
  - I believe that SiTel was [acquired in 2011](https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1258615) by [Dialog Semiconductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_Semiconductor).
- I have found a few Chinese websites that claim to sell this chip, but I have not found a single datasheet for any chip even close to this model. (Maybe it's too old?)

  - One example is [Jotrin](https://www.jotrin.com/product/parts/SC14470). Don't bother trying to click the datasheet link, it just forces you to create an account and once you log in, the datasheet link no longer works.

In the end, I am truly stumped about the function of this chip, nevertheless lots of important info about it. (I could really use just a pinout!) Can anybody find out anything else about this chip?

**EDIT**: I managed to figure out what was wrong with the board (one diode had a loose connection and the other was missing, both due to poor soldering). But I'm still curious about what this chip is!

Comment: Email Dialog Semiconductors for a datasheet? Or one of the [distributors](http://www.oemstrade.com/search/SC14470)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If following the trace in my own X-Plorer guitar's board tells me anything, I believe it to be the USB controller.

Comment: You’re probably right